# if statement get wrong in ms-access 2016

Tags: ms-access

```
Private Sub cmdNew_Click()
if(Me.txtId = "" ) { MsgBox("data is empty please fill it") } else {

CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO DemandTitle (dtId,dtTitle,dtApplicant,dtDate) " & _
" VALUES (" & Me.txtId & ",'" & Me.txtTitle & "','" & Me.txtApplicant & "','" & Me.txtDate & "')"
cmdClear_Click
Demandtitlesubform.Form.Requery

} end if
End Sub
```

get error when if and else command add with if and else it work fine
i need to check the data if data is empty then it show error

Comment: This shows the syntax you need in VBA: [Using If...Then...Else statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-ifthenelse-statements).

Comment: You are using Java-like syntax in VB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Private Sub cmdNew_Click()

    If IsNull(Me!txtId.Value) Then
        MsgBox "data is empty please fill it"
    Else
        CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO DemandTitle (dtId,dtTitle,dtApplicant,dtDate) " & _
        "VALUES (" & Me.txtId & ",'" & Me.txtTitle & "','" & Me.txtApplicant & "',#" & Format(Me!txtDate.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#)"

        cmdClear_Click
        Demandtitlesubform.Form.Requery

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: ? There is no _else with if_.

Comment: @MuhammadFarhan Here's a quick summary for [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)